# How to create click event listener on react-three-fiber / three.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Im trying to listen click events on my react-three-fiber canvas. But Im getting a different event when using `addEventListener`.

`onClick` mesh property returns following event:

```
      <mesh position={[0, 0, 0]} onClick={(e) => console.log('onClick mesh: ', e)}>
        <boxGeometry attach="geometry" args={[10, 10, 10]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="hotpink" wireframe />
      </mesh>
```

```
onClick mesh:  
{dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: Object…} 
// This is the event I need!!
```

And adding a event listener returns the following event:

```
const ThreeEventListener = () => {
  const onClickDocument = (e) => {
    console.log('onClick document listener: ', e)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', onClickDocument, false)
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', onClickDocument)
  })
  return null
}
```

```
onClick document listener:  
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1508, screenY: 427, clientX: 348, clientY: 178…}
// This is a normal DOM event from React that I dont need
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-line-to-box-forked-d6tll?file=/src/index.js:719-1054) (Click the box to fire the events)

Comment: Three does not have events, they come from R3F which watches for generic pointer events, raycasts then, and forms object level events. By adding event listeners to the canvas you'll just get regular pointer events again. Why are you doing this, though, in react you shouldn't touch the dom.

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you got the first time is an instance of `SyntheticEvent` that React [uses](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) as a wrapper over native events, combined with some useful for react-three-fiber fields - here's the [doc](https://gracious-keller-98ef35.netlify.app/docs/api/events/). The doc says there's a native browser event and three.js useful data inside their event implementation (which is what you received).

I suggest taking out what you need out of the native event in the synthetic one:

```
event.nativeEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a close solution using an external library called `three.interaction`:

```
import { Interaction } from 'three.interaction'

const ThreeEventListener = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        // init three.interaction on mount
        const interaction = new Interaction(gl, scene, camera);
    }, [])

    const onClickScene = (event) => {
        console.log('onClick scene listener: ', e)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // attach callbacks to clicks thanks to three.interaction
        scene.on('click', onClickScene)
        return () => scene.on('click', () => {})
    })

    return null
}
```

The event created by three.interaction looks like:

```
onClick scene listener:  InteractionEvent {stopped: false, target: Scene, currentTarget: Scene, type: "click", data: InteractionData, …}
```

Comment: How would you use this? I understand how it works but not where to put it